# Can't create a sync Google calendar Android

Tags: android, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a calendar on google account, I managed to create calendars but none syncs with google and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I know where the problem more or less but I can't fix it.

The code I use is this:

```
public static long createCalendar (Activity activity, String name, String account, boolean local){

        String color = "blue";

        ContentValues calendarvalues = new ContentValues();

        //The account that was used to sync the entry to the device. If the account_type is not {@link #ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL} then the name and
        // type must match an account on the device or the calendar will be deleted.
        if(local) {
            calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMYLOCAL");
            calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
        }else{
            calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account);
            calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account);
        }
        //Local  CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL

        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, name);
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, Color.parseColor(color));
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
//        //None          CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_NONE          Cannot access the calendar
//        //freeBusy      CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_FREEBUSY      Can only see free/busy information about the calendar
//        //Read          CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_READ          Can read all event details
//        //Respond       CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_RESPOND       Can reply yes/no/maybe to an event
//        //Override      CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OVERRIDE      not used
//        //Contributor   CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_CONTRIBUTOR   Full access to modify the calendar, but not the access control settings
//        //Editor        CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_EDITOR        Full access to modify the calendar, but not the access control settings
//        //Owner         CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER         Full access to the calendar
//        //Root          CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_ROOT          Domain admin

        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, account);
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);

//        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_LOCATION, "Spain");


        Uri calUri = null;
        Uri result = null;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            PermissionUtil.requestCalendarPermission(activity);

            return -1;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
        }else{
            calUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        }

        if(calUri != null) {
            if(local) {
                calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMYLOCAL")
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
                        .build();
            }else {
                calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account)
                        .build();
            }

            result = activity.getContentResolver().insert(calUri, calendarvalues);
        }

        if (result != null) {
            try {
                return Long.parseLong(result.getLastPathSegment());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

I think the mistake is in this line :

```
calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account);
```

because I have seen the values returned by the following query:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
     calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
}else{
     calUri = Uri.parse(calendarUriString);
}

String[] projection = new String[]{
            CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
    //      CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS,
 };

 Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(calUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

and the results are as follows:

id: 1 
Name: My Calendar@Local 
Display name: My Calendar 
access level: 700 
AccountName: My Calendar@Local
AccountType: com.local  
ownerAccount: Owner Account visible: 1 
sync: 1

id: 2 
Name: test@gmail.com  
Display name: test@gmail.com 
access level: 700 
AccountName: test@gmail.com 
AccountType: com.google 
ownerAccount: test@gmail.com  
visible: 1  
sync: 1

id: 3  
Name: Test Cal  
Display name: Test Cal  
access level: 700 
AccountName: test@gmail.com  
AccountType: test@gmail.com 
ownerAccount: 1  
visible: 1  
sync: 1

I tried to put the following:

```
calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");
```

but the calendar is not created.

If anyone knows how to do it or have any examples or documentation that may be useful, it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I managed to create calendars but none syncs with google", what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @noogui I'm trying to create a calendar that syncs with google account, not local, and later create events and that this synchronized with the google account that will see it on different devices without having to create for each device. Also it has to be transparent to the user without any Intent to select options.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same Problem - I ended up creating a calendar using the Google Calendar API [insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) function. With the [Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) you should be able to create a Calendar.

Use the `MakeRequestTask#mService` like this:

```
Calendar newCalendar = new Calendar();
newCalendar.setSummary("Calendar Name");
newCalendar.setTimeZone(TIME_ZONE); //assuming you have it as a constant somewhere
String newCalendarId = null;
try {
        com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar insertedCalendar = mService.calendars().insert(newCalendar).execute();
        newCalendarId = insertedCalendar.getId(); 
} catch(Exception ignore){}
```

and then force an account sync with

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(selectedAccount, CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, extras);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I will try them